# Updating combobox model - item listener no longer fires

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener, comboboxmodel

I have a combo box and I update its model with a new `DefaultComboBoxModel` by calling `setModel`. However when I first created the combo box, I registered an `ItemListener` with it by calling `addItemListener`. The problem is after I update the model, the `ItemListener` no longer fires. Do I need to call `addItemListener` with a new `ItemListener` on my combo box after each time I update the model?

Comment: `Do I need to call addItemListener with a new ItemListener on my combo box after each time I update the model?` - Try it and see what happens, then report the results back here.

Comment: I only want to do it if it is necessary. I don't want to have to recreate a new object each time the model is refreshed if it is not necessary.

Comment: `I only want to do it if it is necessary` - you just stated the code doesn't work. Doesn't that tell you that you need to do something? `I don't want to have to recreate a new object each time the model is refreshed if it is not necessary.` - so why are you creating a new model instead of changing the items in the model?  What is different about creating a new model object, but not creating new listeners? Why are you worried about creating a single object. Seems like some kind of micro optimization.

Comment: Good point. I jumped the gun a bit with this. The answer below did the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You can use either of these approaches:

- Use [`getListDataListeners()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractListModel.html#getListDataListeners%28%29) to get the listeners and transfer them to the new model.
- Use [`removeAllElements()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultComboBoxModel.html#removeAllElements%28%29) and recycle the existing model.